# Calculate $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\mid Y]$ where $X,Y$ are independent discrete uniform

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution

$X$, $Y$ - independent random variables such that $$P(X=x)=\dfrac{1}{n}=P(Y=x)$$
for $x \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$. Calculate $\mathbb{E}[\min(X,Y)\mid Y].$

\begin{align}
\psi(j)&=\sum_i i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i\mid Y=j)
\\&=\dfrac{\sum_i i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i \land Y=j)}{P(Y=j)}
\\&=\dfrac{\sum_i i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i \land Y=j)}{\frac{1}{n}}
\\&=n\cdot \sum_i i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i \land Y=j)
\\&=n\cdot\left(\sum_{i\leq j} i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i \land Y=j) + \sum_{i> j} i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i \land Y=j)\right)
\end{align}

Do $\sum_{i\leq j} i\cdot P(\min(X,Y)=i \land Y=j) = \sum_{i\leq j} i\cdot P(X=i \land Y=j)$?

How to compute this sum. What to do with 2nd sum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $i<j$, then
$$P(\min(X,Y)=i\: , Y=j) = P(X=i\:,Y=j).$$
If $i=j$, then
$$P(\min(X,Y)=i \:, Y=j) = P(X\geq j \:, Y=j).$$
For the last sum you can notice, that $\min(X,Y) \leq Y$ with probability $1$, so for $i>j$ we have
$$P(\min(X,Y)=i\: , Y=j) = P(\emptyset)=0.$$
Plugging this into your established formula, you get
\begin{align*}
\psi(j) &=  n\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} iP(X=i,Y=j)+jP(X\geq j,Y=j)\Big) \\
        &= n\Big(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} i \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{j(n-j+1)}{n^2}\Big) \\
        &= \frac{(j-1)j}{2n}+\frac{j(n-j+1)}{n}
\end{align*}
I however would prefer the following method:
\begin{align*}
E[\min(X,Y) \: | \: Y=j] &= E[\min(X,j) \: | \: Y=j] \\
&= E[\min(X,j)] \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{(by independence)} \\
&= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n min(i,j) \\
&= \frac{1}{n} \Big(\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} i + \sum_{i=j}^n j \Big) \\
&= \frac{(j-1)j}{2n}+\frac{j(n-j+1)}{n}
\end{align*}

Comment: How do we know that $jP(X\geq j,Y=j) = \frac{j(n-j+1)}{n^2}$?

Comment: We are using independence to conclude, that $P(X\geq j, Y=j)=P(X\geq j)P(Y=j)$. Furthermore we use, that
$$P(X\geq j) = P(X=j)+P(X=j+1)+\dots+P(X=n) = \frac{n-j+1}{n},$$
since there are $(n-j+1)$ elements $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$ with $i\geq j$.